# Resource not found exception for one layout but not another

Tags: android, android-resources

I am getting `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` upon inflating a layout in Android. The strange thing is I use that exact same resource in a previous screen. The crash only happens upon opening the second screen.

Here's the resource in question (`color_background_pressable`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Darkens the item when it's pressed/focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/colorBackgroundDark" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
</selector>
```

The first screen (which works) contains a recyclerview whose items have the following shape as the background:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/color_background_pressable" />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/linearlayout_recyclerview_item_background_border_width"
        android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/linearlayout_recyclerview_item_background_corner_radius" />
</shape>
```

The second screen (which crashes) also contains a recyclerview:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/story_item_margin_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/story_item_margin_vertical"
    android:background="@color/color_background_pressable"   // Removing this makes it work
    android:elevation="@dimen/story_item_elevation"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/story_item_cover_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_story_image_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/story_item_cover_content_description"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/story_item_title_textview"
        style="@style/text_body_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/story_item_title_margin_top"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:targetApi="o" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This only happens on one phone out of the 3 (1 on emulator) that I've tested on.

Full Logcat error:

```
2020-02-24 13:34:56.031 7399-7399/ca.dccanada.onestoryaday E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ca.dccanada.onestoryaday, PID: 7399
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at ca.dccanada.onestoryaday.ui.program.StoryListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(StoryListAdapter.kt:41)
        at ca.dccanada.onestoryaday.ui.program.StoryListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(StoryListAdapter.kt:14)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:584)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
2020-02-24 13:34:56.033 7399-7399/ca.dccanada.onestoryaday E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:898)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2873)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1779)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable ca.dccanada.onestoryaday:color/color_background_pressable with resource ID #0x7f06003a
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/color_background_pressable.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f06003a
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:837)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:900)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5058)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:234)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:230)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:226)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at ca.dccanada.onestoryaday.ui.program.StoryListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(StoryListAdapter.kt:41)
        at ca.dccanada.onestoryaday.ui.program.StoryListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(StoryListAdapter.kt:14)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
2020-02-24 13:34:56.034 7399-7399/ca.dccanada.onestoryaday E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:584)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:898)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2873)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1779)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
2020-02-24 13:34:56.035 7399-7399/ca.dccanada.onestoryaday E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:189)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:824)
               ... 88 more
```

Comment: can you post the full logcat error please?

Comment: Hi! Some questions for you:
 - Does the state (pressed/unpressed) change between one screen and the other?
 - Are there other layout sizes like xlayout that could be at fault?
 - Are you getting your resources from another module?

Comment: show `color_background_pressable`

Comment: @Logain 1. Maybe? When the item is pressed, the app navigates to the next screen. It is possible the state changes between screen changes. 2. I don't think so. Once I remove the color_background_pressable color, everything works fine. 3. No.